semanticConfiguration empty parameter error
I'm using the Azure AI Search Javascript SDK in my NodeJS app to create a RAG based chatbot. I am uploading data to Blob Storage, creating an index (confirmed to be configured with semantic configuration), and want to run a semantic search.
After defining the search client, I keep getting the following error:
RestError: The parameter 'semanticConfiguration' must not be empty. Alternatively, set a default semantic configuration for this index.
This is how I'm using it in the 'search' method of my searchClient:
const searchResults = await searchClient.search(userInput, {
            queryType: "semantic",
            top: 3,
            semanticConfiguration: "my-semantic-config"
        })

This part of the code is also where I'm getting the error. Unless I'm using incorrect syntax, I don't know why it would give this error if semanticConfiguration is as defined above. Any insight would be appreciated

The  error / issue you encountered  with the semanticConfiguration parameter when using the Azure AI Search JavaScript SDK.
The error message suggests that the semanticConfiguration parameter is either not being passed correctly or is not properly set up in the index.


To resolve this issue, make sure to enable semantic search in Azure AI Search. You can follow the instructions provided in this MSDOC and follow all the below steps.

Using the REST API to enable semantic:


PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourcegroups/{{resource-group}}/providers/Microsoft.Search/searchServices/{{search-service-name}}?api-version=2023-11-01
    {
      "properties": {
        "semanticSearch": "standard"
      }
    }

The below   command retrieves an access token for Azure management and stores it in the token variable. The --resource parameter specifies the resource URL for Azure management, --query accessToken extracts the token from the JSON response, and --output tsv outputs the token as plain text which is use in rest api.
token=$(az account get-access-token --resource=[https://management.azure.com](https://management.azure.com "https://management.azure.com/") --query accessToken --output tsv)


Alternatively, you can enable semantic search through the Azure portal by following this MSDOC.

To add a semanticConfiguration in JavaScript:

const { SearchIndexClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/search-documents");

async function createSemanticConfiguration() {
  const searchServiceEndpoint = process.env.AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT;
  const searchServiceApiKey = process.env.AZURE_SEARCH_ADMIN_KEY;
  const searchIndexName = process.env.AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX;

  const credential = new AzureKeyCredential(searchServiceApiKey);
  const indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceEndpoint, credential);

  const semanticConfigName = "my-semantic-config";

  // Define the semantic configuration
  const semanticConfiguration = {
    name: semanticConfigName,
    prioritizedFields: {
      contentFields: [
        { name: "content" }
      ],
      keywordsFields: [
        { name: "category" }
      ],
      titleField: {
        name: "title"
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    console.log(`Creating or updating semantic configuration: ${semanticConfigName}...`);
    await indexClient.createOrUpdateSemanticConfiguration(searchIndexName, semanticConfigName, semanticConfiguration);
    console.log(`Semantic configuration ${semanticConfigName} created or updated successfully.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to create or update semantic configuration: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

createSemanticConfiguration().catch(console.error);


Thank for mattgotteiner for the sample code to integrate Azure OpenAI and Azure Search, allowing you to create and upload document embeddings, set up a search index, and perform searches with semanticSearch.

